# How to sink current to drive 7-segment LED using a 4026 chip?

Tags: current, integrated-circuit

Am referring to this project here;
http://electronicsclub.info/p_random.htm

with a schematic like so;
[image: Flasher Circuit]

Key points:

- Resistors are not required for the LEDs because the 4026 IC limits the current to about 5mA for each LED
- Outputs of the 4000 series chips can sink and source only about 1mA

I am now actually connecting a 7-segment (single digit) LED which going by the circuit shown, needs to be a common anode component, however i ended up getting a common cathode version and am now wondering how i should reroute the circuit accordingly.

My guess is it's not quite as simple as reversing the above schematic and connecting the LED (single anodes) up to the 9V rail, with the single common cathode down to GND.

Do i now need current-limiting resistors for the 7-segment LEDs ? Would it be one for each (anode) pin out of the 7-segment LED or would just one suffice, ie. on the common cathode before connecting down to GND.

Comment: You need a common cathode display for the circuit shown in your question.

Comment: or an octal inverter/driver between the counter and the common anode display

Answer (score 3):

[image: Diode anode and cathode]

The circuit shows a common cathode configuration. No change (for the same current drive) is required.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ignacio's remark:

- Resistors are not required for the LEDs because the 4026 IC limits the current to about 5mA for each LED

Who says so? AFAIK this is not the case for this chip. When you read the datasheet it might state that the "maximum is 5 mA", but that means that YOU must limit the current to 5mA, by using a suitable series resistor in each segment. You could use one for the display, but only when it is OK for you that for instance and 8 will be much dimmer than a 1.

BTW this [datasheet](https://www.futurlec.com/4000Series/CD4026.shtml) states, in the "recommended operating consitions - static electrical characteristics" the voltage drop for an output current of 6.8 mA, hence that is an allowed current. I could not find an indication that a higher current is allowed, so I would design for a current of 6.8 mA maximum. Modern LED displays can often work well at a much lower current, for instance 1 mA.

Comment: According to the [datasheet](http://www.bucek.name/pdf/4026.pdf) the [absolute max](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MGKfF.jpg) for the IC supply is +-10mA (that is for all outputs combined), so in case of an "8" (seven segments on) the current per segment should be limited to about 1mA or so to be below the max rating.

Comment: NEVER use the "absolute maximum ratings" for a design calculation! The chip is not required to function normally at those values.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that I have used the max rating, did I suggest 10mA? Unless you think that 7mA is also too much but since there is no recommended current level, how much would you suggest?

Comment: Quote "to stay below the max rating", that is using the max rating, isn't it? I added a reference to the allowed current in my answer.